# PyAudio stream delays in callbacks (frames dropped)

Tags: python, audio, real-time, pyaudio

I am trying to use PyAudio in Python for real-time audio processing. I use some standard code for non-blocking streaming using a callback function. However, I notice that there is a delay between the chunks recorded that exceeds the duration of each chunk (i.e. frames dropped I assume).

```
import time
import pyaudio

RATE = 44100
CHUNK_DUR = 1
CHANNELS = 1

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

prev_callback_time = 0.0

def callback(data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global prev_callback_time
    print(f"Time when first sample of input buffer was captured: {time_info['input_buffer_adc_time']}.Expected time: {prev_callback_time + CHUNK_DUR}")
    delay = prev_callback_time + CHUNK_DUR - time_info['input_buffer_adc_time']
    print(f"Delay: {delay} seconds ({delay/CHUNK_DUR * 100} %)")
    prev_callback_time = time_info['input_buffer_adc_time']
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

chunk_len = int(CHUNK_DUR * RATE)

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, input_device_index=0, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE,
                input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk_len, stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.5)

stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

The callback processing time is just ~0.0002 seconds so the delay is not because of that. Even using a chunk duration of 1 second, I can see delays up to 200% of that (i.e. 2 seconds of delay)
Is there any way I can check whether I really missed 2 secs of audio?

An interesting observation is that the delay is either ~0% or exactly 200%! That means that it sometimes skips frames that are exactly equal to 2 chunks in length

Comment: A buffer of 44100 samples is very long IMO – I'd do something like 4096 samples.

Comment: I tried and same applies for 1024 or 4096 samples: the delay jumps to exactly 200% often, despite of the frames_per_buffer I use

Comment: The more your `p.open()` call resembles the [example](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o) in the documentation, the happier you're likely to be. In particular, the example computes several parameters from the input audio stream, where you have opted for hardcoded numbers. Be boring, copy the docs, get it working, and _then_ branch out with variations and experiments.

Comment: Thank you @J_H for your advice. Even following that example it looks like some frames/chunks are missed so I assume it's inevitable. What's important in this case is the frames_per_buffer is small such that when frames/chunks are missed the effect is not noticeable